# Does an ADC with bipolar input has more resolution on the negative "part"?

Tags: binary, signal-processing, twos-complement, adc

I'm trying to understand if the negative part of a bipolar ADC has more resolution than the positive.

For simplicity, let's say I have a 3 bit ADC, for a total of 8 possible values. Let's also say that the ADC presents the values in two's complement.

So, if the ADC's binary output "000" is zero volts on the input, then I would have more three steps for positive inputs ("001", "010" and "011"). But for negative inputs, I would have four possible steps ("111", "110", "101" and "100"), right? So, for example, if I am using a voltage reference (**Vref = 0.8 V**) such that each step (**LSB = 0.2 V**) is 0.2 V (so "000" is 0.0 V, '001' is 0.2 V, '111' is -0.2 V, etc.), wouldn't I be able to reach a maximum of 0.6 V ("011") and a minimum of -0.8 V ("100")? Or am I missing something here?

I appreciate in advance any kind of help. Thank you :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Bipolar capable ADCs usually use even number of bits. It’s the same resolution, just shifted by offset. In your example for positive all 8 voltage steps are available. So the voltage range should is different due to zero offset to be different. With numbers, positive range is [0v, 0.8v], negative [-0.386v, +0.386v] step ~0.114v in both cases. *If I get how Vref is interpreted by ADC*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mano's Digital Design book, you always have one extra number for negative values compared to positive ones in 2's complement world.
Please take a look at the below table from Mano's book:
[image]

As you can see from the table this stems from the fact that `0000` is used for number zero which is neither positive nor negative but make use of positive numbers representation in 2's complement world
(+0 = `0000` ==> MSb, namely sign bit, is 0). However, it does not matter at all when you are working with an ADC. With a 4-bit ADC it is expected to have 16 binary levels and already you have it
from -8 to +7 binary levels.